# django-widget-tweaks with django custom tags

Tags: python, django, django-widget-tweaks

I am using django-widget-tweaks to render my django form fields.

Now I need to show the return value of a custom django tag as the value of my render field.

This is my template tag

```
from forex_python.bitcoin import BtcConverter

@register.simple_tag
def btc_price_in_sgd():
    coin_obj = BtcConverter()
    price = coin_obj.get_latest_price('SGD')
    return price
```

I used the return value of this filter as my form input field

here is the code I used to show in template

```
{% render_field exchange_form.price class="form-control" value=btc_price_in_sgd %}
```

but this is not working